# From keyword not found where expected error while joining tables

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT s.Store_name,
i.type, 
s.city,
s.zip,
i.item_name,
s.store open date,
s.region
 FROM OCT16_STACK_UCH.OOW_DEMO_STORES_FIN s
    inner JOIN OCT16_STACK_UCH.OOW_DEMO_ITEMS_FIN i
    ON OCT16_STACK_UCH.OOW_DEMO_STORES_FIN.id = OCT16_STACK_UCH.OOW_DEMO_ITEMS_FIN.item_id;
```

As you can see FROM is listed but apparently i'm not putting this in the right place?

Answer (score 4):

You have two `FROM` clause in your query, remove one.

Then you need to escape the space in `store open date` column using *double quotes*

Also you have defined `Alias` name for the both the tables so use alias name in `join` condition

```
SELECT s.store_name, 
       s.type, 
       s.city, 
       s.zip, 
       i.item_name, 
       s."store open date",  --here
       s.region 
FROM   oct16_stack_uch.oow_demo_stores_fin s 
       INNER JOIN oct16_stack_uch.oow_demo_items_fin i 
               ON s.id = i.item_id; --used alias name
```